# 48-hour transit visa in UAE.Timestamp of transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, uae

I am an Indian national arriving in Abu Dhabi on 28th August at 8pm and departing Abu Dhabi at 12.45 am on 30th August.

I was thinking to apply for a short-term transit visa for 48 hours. However when I fill the form it just asks for my arrival date, 28th (and not the time when I arrive) and says the 48-hour visa is valid until 29th August.

Please advise if I can still apply for 48-hour visa, since there is no timestamp input provision on the website.

Comment: Just to be sure, with "12:45 am", do you mean 45 minutes after midnight, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just 45 minutes after midnight

Comment: Can you let us know if everything went according to plan?

Comment: Yes, it did. No issues with 48 hr visa

Answer (score 2):

It is my **impression** that the transit visa will not have an arrival date or departure date, it has just an issue date and a validity (14 days from issue date), and the 48 hours count from actual time of arrival, but I have a hard time confirming it.

The [official UAE site](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visit-visas/transit-visa#:%7E:text=Transit%20visas%20for%2048%20hours&text=The%20validity%20of%20the%20visa,self%20against%20a%20white%20background) says

> The validity of the visa is 48 hours from entry into the UAE, and you must leave the UAE within 48 hours from arrival.

My **guess** is that the arrival date is just there to make sure the visa is not requested too far in advance (since it would no longer be valid by the time you arrive): you cannot enter a date more than 14 days in the future. The few readable images of 48 hours transit visas I found did not have an arrival or departure date at all.

However **I have a hard time confirming it with hard evidence**. Your best bet is probably to contact them, either Etihad:

> +971 (0) 56 677 0326
>
> visaonarrival@etihad.ae

Or ICP:

> https://icp.gov.ae/en/contact-us/
>
> +971 2 4955555
>
> contactus@icp.gov.ae

If you don't get an answer in time (or you get a negative answer), then you should use a 96 hours transit visa, which requires a fee of 50 AED.

Also remember that you need a hotel booking (or other evidence of someone hosting you) for transits longer than 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. It's very helpful. I have mailed ethiad. Hope they reply in time. Meanwhile, I was thinking to proceed with applying for 48 hours transit visa and see what the final visa document looks like. If it's until 29th August, I reapply for 4 days. What do you think

Comment: The problem is that while the document itself apparently only shows its date of issue, not how long you can stay in the UAE. So it could tell you "valid from 27/08/2023" and that would not tell you if you can stay 48 hours or 2 calendar days. Given the fact it takes 3-4 days to get the visa and there's only 5 days left before your flight, I would be you I would either call them to know for sure, or apply directly for the 96 hour visa.

Comment: The number is not reachable

Comment: I got a reply from email stating that I have 14 days maximum before the flight to apply for this Visa

Comment: It means I can still apply it right

Comment: You can apply for the visa at the earliest 14 days before the flight (because the visa will be valid for 14 days once issued), but they say it takes 3-4 days to process the application, so you should apply now to get it in time for your flight.

Comment: Have you tried both number? Etihad and ICP? ICP is the authority which delivers the visa. There's also a live chat on the ICP page linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply. I applied for the visa and got it in 1 hour. They are super fast. In the visa, it's mentioned that it's 48 hours from date of entry so think it shall be fine

Comment: @GauravTaparia the ambiguity lies in the fact that is 48 hours from “date” of entry, which I find weird, but would then be 2 calendar days, as opposed to 48 hours from “time” of entry. Did you get any answer from either?

Comment: I had to upload my onward flight tickets for getting this visa. They would have checked and approved it. If it wasnt from time of entry, they would not have approved it. Further, there's no validity date mentioned on visa. Only issue date is mentioned. So I presume once we enter it's valid for 48 hrs from time of entry